# Multiplying scalar by a column vector?

Tags: vectors

[image]

For the question above, I understand we multiply the scalar by both the x and y components of the column vector to get our answer. But what is the proof of this distributive property, why do we multiply both the top and and bottom numbers?

Comment: That's the definition of scalar multiplication of a column vector. You can't prove a definition. You can ask why we make this definition, and the reason is it's the most obvious way of making $\Bbb{R}^2$ (more generally $\Bbb{R}^n$) into a vector space, and it conforms to our geometric intuition of vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the vector
$$
\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}
$$
as an arrow from the origin to the point $(3, 4)$ in the plane. Then, $7\mathbf{v}$ is a copy of that arrow stretched by a factor of $7$, from the origin out to a point $7$ times as far away, but in the same direction. What are the coordinates of the head of that arrow? $(7 \cdot 3, 7 \cdot 4) = (21, 28)$. Thus,
$$
7\mathbf{v} = 7\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 21 \\ 28 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You came close on your own since *it is the distributive property* that establishes this fact.

First, consider what it means to write ${\bf u} = \pmatrix{ 3 \\ 4}$?

It is shortcut for $${\bf u} = 3 {\bf \hat{u}}_1 + 4 {\bf \hat{u}}_2$$ where $\bf \hat{u}_i$ are the basis vectors used.

So to evaluate the scalar product you have the following expansion based on the distributive property

$$ \lambda\; {\bf u} = \lambda \left( 3 {\bf \hat{u}}_1 + 4 {\bf \hat{u}}_2 \right) =(\lambda 3) {\bf \hat{u}}_1 + (\lambda 4) {\bf \hat{u}}_2 $$

And the above is written with the shorthand notation of vectors as

$$ \lambda\; {\bf u} = \pmatrix{ \lambda\, 3 \\ \lambda\, 4} $$